# Can i use kotlinx.html with document in kotlin-js?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlinx-html

Now i work on kotlin-js project. And i want to Add some HTML tag in my index.html. So i want to use kotlinx.html. Is it available using kotlinx.html in kotlin-js code?

Like This one

```
import kotlin.browser.document

document.create.p{+"hello world}
```

If it isn't please let me know how to add Tag Attribute or HTML Tag using kotlin-js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kotlinx-html(npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kotlinx-html) for js.
Download latest version of kotlinx-html from npm

```
npm install kotlinx-html
```

[Here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/blob/master/README-JS.md) is the Readme for Kotlin/JS users. You can naturally build html as you do in kotlin/JVM.